# ¿Como obtener el valor del Id de DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy trabajando con ASP.NET MVC 5, estoy en la necesidad de obtener el valor del `Id` del `Item` seleccionado del `DropDownList`, cuando digo valor me rerfiero al `Id` no a la `Descripción`.

El `DropDowList` esta cargado de la siguiente manera:
Controller

```
// GET: Proveedor/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var proveedor = SdProveedor.ListaTipoDocumentoIdentidad();
        ViewBag.ListaProveedores = new SelectList(proveedor, "Id", "Descripcion");

        var model = new ProveedorDto();
        return View(model);
    }
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DocumentoIdentidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("myDropDown", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaProveedores)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ahora necesito obtener el valor del `Id` Seleccionado del `DropDownList`, ¿Tendría que crear un evento `Changed` o algo parecido que cuando seleccione un `Item` tome el valor y poder enviarlo al modelo para hacer el `POST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mvc no existen los eventos, tienes que realizar un post al action Create para que el modelbinding asigne el valor a la propiedad

pero deberias utilizar

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=> x.ProveedorId, (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaProveedores)
```

En el ProveedorDto tienes qie definir una propiedad que asigne el valor al combo y que ademas defina el nombre con el cual va a mapear cuando vuelva

Recuerda que modelbinding buscara coincidencias entre el name del control y la propiedad del model que define el action si hya coincidencia asignara el valor

Comment: Leandro, he notado que cuando ejecuto la aplicación y pongo ver código en la pagina se genera automaticamente el código html que crea el razor. `<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="Direccion">Direcci&#243;n</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Direccion" name="Direccion" type="text" value="" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Direccion" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>` me genera el id

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar el método siguiente para obtener el Id del dropdownlist:

```
$('#tusDropDownList').change(function () {   
    /* Obtener el valor de tus dropdownlist */
    var selectedId = $(this).val();
});
```

Espero que esto ayude...